# How to add a custom MDCUnitOfWork in CamelContext in Camel 3.4.2

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

How to add a custom `MDCUnitOfWork` in CamelContext in Camel 3.4.2. Earlier I could add using `camelContext.setUnitOfWorkFactory(..)` but now, I'm not seeing that method. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CamelContext` interface is simplified in Apache Camel 3.x, providing only methods most relevant for end user. You can access all advanced methods with [`CamelContext#adapt`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/latest/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#adapt-java.lang.Class-).

See [Apache Camel 3 migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_extended_camelcontext):

> The APIs on `CamelContext` has been reduced a bit to focus on relevant API for Camel end users. The advanced use-cases and for SPI and component developers, then some of the APIs from CamelContext has been moved to ExtendedCamelContext which you can access via adapt.

You can find example in [`CustomUnitOfWorkFactoryTest`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/impl/CustomUnitOfWorkFactoryTest.java)

```
context.adapt(ExtendedCamelContext.class).setUnitOfWorkFactory(new MyUnitOfWorkFactory());
```

Comment: update for camel 4 (also updated in the test linked above):
`context.getCamelContextExtension().addContextPlugin(UnitOfWorkFactory.class, new MyUnitOfWorkFactory());`